# How can I detect french or us culture from string decimal format?

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

I have two string : `1.5` and `1,5`

I want to convert this to decimal but I want to detect automatically the culture : with point us culture and with comma fr culture

What is the best way to do this ?

Comment: You can't do this with 100% certainty, because the comma could mean a German or a Russian culture, and the dot can be an US or an UK culture.

Comment: Even worse, what does `1,543` mean? It could be `1.543` or `1543` depending on culture.

Comment: If the rules you want to follow **are that simple** then do what you said, look for a point, if you find one then you have us culture, if you find a comma then you have the fr culture. What is the question here? The best way to do **exactly** what you asked for is 1-2 if-statements.

Comment: If, on the other hand, those two cultures are merely examples of what you want and you want the full range of cultures then no, that can't be done. Simple as that.

Comment: How to get simply the NumberDecimalSeparator of my string ? I want to get a char. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If your numbers can't contain thousand group separators you could use this:

```
var usCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
var frCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
NumberStyles ns = NumberStyles.Any & ~NumberStyles.AllowThousands;  // without thousands

string[] strings = {"1.5", "1,5"};
foreach (string s in strings)
{
    decimal d;
    bool isUsCulture = decimal.TryParse(s, ns, usCulture, out d);
    bool isFrCulture = decimal.TryParse(s, ns, frCulture, out d);
}
```

Note that you can now detect the culture but only if it contains the decimal separator. A number like "2" could be us or fr.

Comment: If I may attach to this question...
If I had an application in multiple countries with different number styles, what would be the best way to add an value (number) to my database, and make the number 'universal'?

Comment: @FiN: there is no "universal" number, but you could specify the culture. However, your question doesnt make sense because a number should be stored as number and not as string, f.e. as `DECIMAL(18,4)`.

Comment: That's why I'm asking, if i get the value of field where it says `1,24` what will happen...
Will it save it to the database as `1.24` or...

Comment: That depends on your code which you havent shown. `decimal.TryParse(s, ns, frCulture, out d)` will parse it to a decimal. Then just use a sql-parameter with `SqlDbType.Decimal`. Of course it must be a decimal in the database too.

Comment: This is just a question, nothing with hands on... Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
you insert this code in line first on function program.
you use to the separators `"."` 
eg:`decimal.Parse("0.2")`

```
var usCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = usCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = usCulture ;
```